# Export a PuTTY session to command line

Tags: putty

I would like to create a Windows batch file that will run a PuTTY session.
I already configured the PuTTY session within the PuTTY UI.

Is there any way to generate the command line from an existing session?

Answer (score 0):

If you ask whether PuTTY can generate the command-line for you, no it cannot.

Note that you cannot configure most PuTTY session options from a command-line anyway.

But you can refer to the saved session using `-load session_name` switch.